# Приложение с авторизацией flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

когда приложение скомпелировалось и запустилось android studio мне вывел следующие сообщения:

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation( 9046): eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa3056c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaa303350)

после того как я нажимаю на кнопку sing in в приложении выводит следующее:
W/BiChannelGoogleApi( 9046): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@fb9d369
I/flutter ( 9046): There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

вот коды страниц:
main

```
import 'package:flutter_app/Setup/singin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

singin

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Pages/home.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String _email, _password;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sing in'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField (
              // ignore: missing_return
              validator: (input){
                if (input.isEmpty) {
                  return'Please type an email';
                }
              },
              onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Email'
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField (
              // ignore: missing_return
              validator: (input){
                if (input.isEmpty) {
                  return'Please type an password';
                }
                if(input.length < 6) {
                  return 'Password needs to be atleast 6 characters';
                }
              },
              onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password'
              ),
              obscureText: true,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: singIn,
                child: Text('Sing in'),
                )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> singIn () async {
    final formState = _formKey.currentState;
    if(formState.validate()) {
      formState.save();
      try{
        // ignore: unused_local_variable
        FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)) as FirebaseUser;
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(user: null,)));
      }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

home

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget{
  const Home({
    Key key,
    @required this.user
  }):super(key: key);
  final FirebaseUser user;

  @override
  _HomeState createState()=>_HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('${widget.user.email}'),
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: У вас в Firebase, пользователь создан? Firebase Auth включен? Firebase с проектом соединен?

Comment: пользователь создан! Firebase Auth включен (авторизация по email)! настраивал синхронизацию с приложением по инструкции на сайте firebase, так же в файле pubspec.yaml поставил строчку firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5 после чего сделал Packages get

Comment: `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(user: null,)));` эта строчка настораживает, вы передаете `null`...

Comment: И эта: `FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)) as FirebaseUser;`, лучше использовать сделать так:`FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)).user;`

Comment: Ни проблему ищите на стороне Firebase Auth или подключения Firebase.